# CSS3 animation using keyframes alternate not firing

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

I am trying to achieve a dead simple animation using rotations and keyframes, the animation is fired when the user hovers an element.

The problem is that when the user stops hovering the element the animation is not fired backwards
A live demo of my problem http://jsfiddle.net/9eWhC/

Κeep in mind that the animations declaration has been added to the hover event

```
.b:hover {
    z-index:900;
    -webkit-transform:rotateX(-180deg);
    -moz-transform:rotateX(-180deg);
    -webkit-animation-name: spinz;
    -moz-animation-name: spinz;
    -ms-animation-name: spinz;
    -o-animation-name: spinz;
    animation-name: spinz;
    animation-direction: alternate;
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
    -moz-animation-duration: 3s;
    -ms-animation-duration: 3s;
    -o-animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-duration: 3s;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`alternate` cannot help you here - you need to play the animation at least twice *for the same state*, either normal (`.b`) or hover (`.b:hover`)to notice the effect of `alternate`. What you need to do in order to have the same animation reverset when hovering off is set that same animation on the normal state (`.b`) as well, but with an `animation-direction` of `reverse`.

[modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9eWhC/2/)

Comment: This is a good approach but still the effect is not quite what I want, I think that I will stick on using JS in order to polish it, by the way I love your work on codepen